# How to code spring custom annotation which works like ibatis Select annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, customization

I am trying to make a custom annotation like ibatis `@Select`.

Anyway, In conclusion, the goal is

- append some data into the parameter which the method has custom annotation

First take a look end point - `ArtistNodeRepository.java`

```
@Repository
public interface ArtistNodeRepository {

    @CreateNode(tid = "artist")
    public Node create(Map data) throws Exception;
}
```

What want to do with `CreateNode` annotation is put `data.put("type", "artist")` into parameter Map.

Here is the Annotation - `CreateNode.java`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Documented
public @interface CreateNode {
    String[] values() default "";
    String tid();
}
```

To controller annotation, I prepared this `BeanPostProcessor` - `NodeAnnotationProcessor.java`

```
@Component
public class NodeAnnotationProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;

    @Autowired
    public NodeAnnotationProcessor(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) {
        super();
        this.configurableListableBeanFactory = configurableListableBeanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        this.scanNodeAnnotation(bean, beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
       // this.scanNodeAnnotation(bean, beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    protected void scanNodeAnnotation(Object bean, String beanName){
        this.configureMethodAction(bean);
    }

    private void configureMethodAction(Object bean){
        Class<?> managedBeanClass = bean.getClass();
        ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback methodCallback = new NodeMethodCallback(configurableListableBeanFactory, bean);
        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(managedBeanClass, methodCallback);
    }
}
```

I am not clear where to put `MethodCallback` to `postProcessBeforeInitialization` or `postProcessAfterInitialization`. In my thought, it would be in `after` since I am trying to manipulate parameter of the method

Finally, this is the `MethodCallback` - `NodeMethodCallback.java`

```
public class NodeMethodCallback implements ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NodeMethodCallback.class);

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    private Object bean;
    private static int AUTOWIRE_MODE = AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME;

    public NodeMethodCallback(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Object bean) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        logger.info("doWith method info :: " + String.valueOf(bean) + "." + bean.getClass().getName());
        /*
            What I expected is Printing ArtistNodeRepository Class with create Method
            But It prints something like ...

            SessionFlashMapManager
            DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator
            ...
        */


        try {
           logger.info("When I call you :: " + method.getName()); // I expect method which contains @CreateNode annotation, but it is not ...
            Annotation[] methodAnnotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            boolean isTarget = false;
            String tid = "";
            for(Annotation anno : methodAnnotations) {
                logger.info("annotation Class :: " + anno.getClass().getName());
                if(isTarget) break;
                if(anno instanceof CreateNode) {
                    logger.info("CreateNode annotation found");
                    CreateNode createNode = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(CreateNode.class);
                    tid = createNode.tid();
                    isTarget = true;
                } 
            }
            if(!isTarget) return;
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);

            /*
                Do Somthing with Parameter ...
                Do Somthing with Parameter ...
                Do Somthing with Parameter ...
                Do Somthing with Parameter ...
                Do Somthing with Parameter ...
            */
        } catch (Exception e ){
            logger.error("ERROR", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is ... in `doWith` I could not find `ArtistNodeRepository` instance.

What should I do with `MethodCallback` and `BeanPostProcessor` to achieve the goal?

Good sample codes would be nice as well as good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you misunderstood the useage of `ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods`. it means iterate the class method if match callback. rather than when invoke method callback.

```
  public static void doWithMethods(Class<?> clazz, MethodCallback mc, MethodFilter mf) {
        // Keep backing up the inheritance hierarchy.
        Method[] methods = getDeclaredMethods(clazz);
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (mf != null && !mf.matches(method)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                mc.doWith(method);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Not allowed to access method '" + method.getName() + "': " + ex);
            }
        }
        if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
            doWithMethods(clazz.getSuperclass(), mc, mf);
        }
        else if (clazz.isInterface()) {
            for (Class<?> superIfc : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
                doWithMethods(superIfc, mc, mf);
            }
        }
    }
```

i think you can use aspect. like this.

```
    @Around("execution(public * org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.*(..))")
    // @Around("@annotation(Repository)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        CreateNode createNode = method.getAnnotation(CreateNode.class);
        if(createNode != null) {
            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            // do your business

        }
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
```

hope can help you

Comment: https://github.com/luolibing/coding-life/blob/master/spring-boot-sample/spring-boot-jpa/src/main/java/cn/tim/mail/config/JpaConfiguration.java